# Storing selected drop down list value in a variable in PHP

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I have accessed a MySql database, retrieved the values from the relevant table and put them in a drop down list using:

```
$material_query=          "SELECT material FROM materials";
$material_query_run =     mysql_query($material_query);
echo "<select>";
while   ($material_query_array=   mysql_fetch_array($material_query_run) ){
        echo "<option value='' >".$material_query_array['material']."</option>";                        
}echo "</select>";
```

How would I now store the selected value from the drop down list within a variable? I think that I need to use POST however, I cannot figure out how.

Comment: a html form would be the usual approach

Comment: Do you mean get selected value from view? You should use JavaScript (i.e jQuery framework) to get selected value from DOM or if you meant get value of select after sending form use `$_POST` to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the select element needs to be inside a form, which you can then submit and the data submitted (by post or get) can then be processed.

Your select box needs to have a name attribute so that it can be identified. Also you need to have a value in the value attribute of the option elements, as this is the data that is sent.

For example, on your page (e.g. page.php) you would have your current code inside html form tags:

```
// The Form
<form action="page.php" method="post">
    <?php
    $material_query = "SELECT material FROM materials";
    $material_query_run = mysql_query( $material_query );
    echo "<select name='mySelect'>";
    while   ( $material_query_array = mysql_fetch_array( $material_query_run ) ) {
        echo "<option value='".$material_query_array['material']."' >".$material_query_array['material']."</option>";                        
    }
    echo "</select>";
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>

//Process the form
//check if form is submitted
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
    //is submitted
    $variable = $_POST['mySelect'];
    //DO STUFF WITH DATA
}
```

So here I have done the following:

- Added the form tags ( SEE: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp )
- Added the name attribute to the select tags
- Added the same value that the select displays to the value attribute of the option tags
- Added code to process the form when it is submitted ( See the above link again )

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed and helpful reply! 
Is there any way of doing this without using a submit button? ie. the variable updates as I am changing the drop down list selection automatically without the need for submission.

Comment: No problem. Unfortunately you can't change a PHP variable after the page has loaded without sending another request to the server (as PHP is executed on the server side). However you can send data using the conventional method, as described above, or you can use AJAX, which involved running other PHP scripts without reloading the page using JavaScript to send a request in the background. You should definitely read up on AJAX as it could help with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like:

```
<form action="post.php" method="post" name="select_form">
    <?php
       $material_query="SELECT material FROM materials";
       $material_query_run =mysql_query($material_query);
       echo "<select name=\"selectbox\">";
       while   ($material_query_array=   mysql_fetch_array($material_query_run) ){
         echo "<option value='".$material_query_array['material']."'>".$material_query_array['material']."</option>";                        
       }
       echo "</select>";
    ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Then in `post.php`

```
<?php
     if($_POST){
        $select=$_POST['selectbox'];
     }
?>
```

On a side note use PDO (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or MySQLI (https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) as the MySql interface is outdated.

Answer (score 0):

When the user hits the submit button, the data will need to be sent to your PHP processor, either using GET or POST.  In your processor, then you would access the SELECT field values just like any other form element.

```
<form action="processor.php" method="POST">
// FORM ELEMENTS HERE
<input type="submit" value="Go!">
</form>
```

In your processor:

```
<?php
$selectbox = $_POST['selectbox'];
```

Now you can sanitize and use the variable `$selectbox` in your script or pass it to your database.